# $\min\{x^2y\}$ problem

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, optimization

Given two constants $A$ and $B$, where $0<A<1$ and $B>0$. For two positive numbers $x$ and $y$, how to find $\min\{x^2y\}$ such that $x$ and $y$ have the following constraints:

$2B^x-B^y \le A  \ \ (\textrm{if }  y>x$)

or

$B^y \le  A  \ \ (\textrm{if }  y\le x$)

I have tried to use MATLAB to find some solutions for some specific settings of $A$ and $B$, but cannot find a general solution to $x$ and $y$ in terms of $A$ and $B$. Any ideas are very welcome.

Comment: Hmm. Why do you think there would be a nice closed-form solution? The solution would highly depend on $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 1):

When A = 1/2 and B = $\pi$, then, as there is no x,y that fit the criterion, there is no minimum.  A general solution is a fantasy.

Comment: Sorry, $x$ and $y$ are two positive numbers (not integers only). The problem has been  slightly changed.